# Why i cant append my custom object to array?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

so first i made a custom object :

```
import Foundation
class Website { 
             var name:String
             var pictureLabel:String

    init(title:String,pictureLabel:String) {
        name = title
        pictureLabel = picture
    }
}
```

---

and then on my tableviewcontroller class :

```
class ViewController:
 UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var websites = [Website]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")


        websites.append(Website(title: "facebook.com", pictureLabel: "facelogo"))


        print(websites)
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return websites.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.label.text = websites[indexPath.row].name
        return cell }
```

error : Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file

Comment: On what row do you get the error?

Comment: Are you sure you did a set up MyCell correctly? Does it have in Interface Builder (or in Storyboard) the correct name - “MyCell”?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it didnt show it .. but even wehen i tried to print the array as :print(websites) i got [MyBrowser.Website] ----( MyBrowser is the project name)

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov yah i checked the identifier and its the same

Comment: Guys plz i really need help with this

Comment: Unfortunately the error message you've included here seems to be unrelated to the code you've included. Have you pasted the error correctly? Do you have a variable named "file" somewhere else in your project?

Comment: @Mohamedaboghali are you sure you have linked the UITableView to the storyboard?

Comment: @Mohamedaboghali, I noticed you found an answer [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128402#403681) Can you edit your post or post your answer so that others with the same problem can fix it?

Comment: I don't see how the code that you've included here will even compile. In your `WebSite` class you have `init(title:,picture:)`, but you call it with `Website(title:pictureLabel:)`. There is a mismatch between `picture` and `pictureLabel`. Please update your question to include the current code that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was on that line

```
tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
```

it should be

```
 tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")`
```

Comment: but still i cant figure why it wont print the contents of array  on the output windowns..  what i got on the output window is [MyprogectName.List]